# Backbone ignore posting specific attributes on save?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model that consists of a `contacts` array that gets created by me, however, on `model.save` I don't want this array to be part of the save. Can anyone recommend how this is achieved, is it simply a matter of creating an object of key/values I do want to `POST` and pass these in to the save?

**Model**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "position": "Manager",
    "department": "Finance",
    "manages": [
        {
            "id": "FR-1",
            "name": "Jane Doe"
        },
        {
            "id": "FR-23",
            "name": "Simon Wakes"
        }
    ],
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": "C123",
            "name": "Julian Norris",
            "telephone": "0123456789"
        }
    ]
}
```

Maybe I need to do something like:

```
var newModelData = {
    "name": "Joe Alexander Bloggs",
    "department": "Human Resources"
}

this.model.save(newModelData);
```

Comment: You need to override syncing behaviour http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync

Comment: Executive summary: override `toJSON` to remove what you don't want sent and use a separate `serialize` to provide data for views.